# NextJS useState Array not properly setting the state

Tags: reactjs, arrays, next.js, use-state

I'm trying to save an array to a `useState` array but the state is not updating properly.
When the code below is run, the variable `first` will return the values properly but the variable "data" returns an empty array.

When I add `console.log("restart")` under line 5, it is shown that it is `console.log` twice when the page is first loaded and another time after the `useEffect` is called.

```
import { jsonFile } from "../public/data.json";
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

...

    const [data, setdata] = useState<any>([]) //line 5

    let first:any = [];

    function getFirst(){
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonFile.length; i++){
            if(jsonFile[i].number == 1){
                first.push(jsonFile[i])
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getFirst()
        setdata(old => [...old, first])
        console.log(first)
        console.log(data)
    },[])
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `first` is an array you should change your `setdata` call to:

```
setdata((old) => [...old, ...first]);
```

Also, you should change the type of the `data` state to `any[]`:

```
const [data, setdata] = useState<any[]>([])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to destructure `first` so that all the elements from first are spread in data array.

You can do something like this:

```js
setData([...data, ...first]);
```

What I've done here is call the setData function and passed an array where the old contents of `data` array are first populated and then the contents of `first` array are populated.

Also, try to use camel case when naming useState functions, instead of `setdata` you should use the naming `setData`, it's more consistent with the notations :)